# resizing item renderer when horizontalList resizes

Tags: apache-flex, user-interface, flex3, horizontallist

I have a HorizontalList that is resized at runtime. The problem is that the items are not adjusting their height to the height of the HorizontalList.
I use an item renderer (vBox) which has its height set to 100%. But the items always stay at their initial size.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this:

I added a resize listener to the `horizontalList` and adjust its `rowHeight` manually in the handler. Works fine so far.